# Importing javascript from CDN in nbextension?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to use https://crontab.guru/ in my nbextension, how can I include this from cdn in nbextension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Specify your CDN in the config  -

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        cron: '//unpkg.com/cronstrue@latest/dist/cronstrue.min'
    }
});
```

**Do not append .js**

In your AMD module which defines load_ipython_extension, define cron as dependency-

```
define(['cron'], function(cron){

    function load_ipython_extension(){
        console.log(cron.toSrting("* * * * *"));

    }

    return {
        load_ipython_extension: load_ipython_extension
    };
});
```