# Download js from cdn using javascript define

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn

How to load javascript from CDN using "define" https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD?

I want to use https://github.com/bradymholt/cronstrue inside https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/blob/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/autosavetime/main.js

This is needed for my nbextension [Importing javascript from CDN in nbextension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458388/importing-javascript-from-cdn-in-nbextension)

Comment: where is your code?  what have you tried?  what exact problem or error message do you see?

Comment: This is my code https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/blob/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/autosavetime/main.js

Comment: I want to use https://github.com/bradymholt/cronstrue in the above main.js

Comment: I want to maka a same